# Redirect to image from PHP result error 500

Tags: php, html, image

Here is the HTML

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/img.php?image=1" />
```

This is the img.php file

```
<?php
switch ($_GET['image']) {
    case "1":
        $image = 'photo-1.jpg';
        break;
    case "2":
        $image = 'photo-2.jpg';
        break;
    case "3":
        $image = 'photo-3.jpg';
        break;
    default:
        $image = 'photo-1.jpg';
}
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
readfile('some/folder/'.$image);
?>
```

When I access http://example.com/images/img.php?image=1 directly, always success, never error 500.
But when I put it on src, it's generate error 500, sometimes.

Why? Is there anything wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: if it's only sometimes, check to see if it's set/not empty

Comment: "Why?" - unknown.  "Is there anything wrong?" - check your Apache logs to see what's going on.  It's impossible to tell without more info, and the logs often contain the key details.

Comment: check your logs also, what did they show?

Comment: here is the log : [Wed Oct 18 05:47:34.378089 2017] [:error] [pid 732797] (12)Cannot allocate memory: [client 36.73.22.59:10526] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/cdsxtwrf/public_html/images/img.php

Answer (score 0):

solved
just increase php memory_limit and everything is fine